# How to make a gallery with dynamic images from URLs?

Tags: images, gallery

I have a link in my API that generates a list of URLs for some images.

I want to display theses images in a nice gallery in WordPress.

I couldn't find anything in the tutorials giving me hints on how to do that, so I would like to know:

**Is there any way to use a gallery feature using a list of URLs?**